# How to map dictionary values to values of dataframe column by matching dictionary key to column name python

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I would like to map weights from dictionary to some columns in dataframe and calculate index (weighted average actually).

```
import pandas as pd
people = pd.DataFrame(
{
    'name': ['Robert', 'Sam', 'Tom'],
    'height': [160, 170, 180],
    'IQ': [100, 140, 120],
    'income': [12, 7, 4]
}
)
weights = {
    'height': 0.1,
    'IQ': 0.6,
    'income': 0.3
}
```

Desired index in sudocode would be:

```
people['index'] = 
mean(
people['height'] * weight of height which is 0.1 + 
people['IQ'] * weight of IQ which is 0.6 + 
people['income'] * weight of income which is 0.3
)
```

I tried using `map` but I would have to reformat dataframe to long format and map dictionary to values of single column and for the sake of this task I cant. And I dont know how to map it to column names

Comment: Can you manually calculate and tell me what is expected value in index column of first observation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use lambda function:

```
people['index'] = people.apply(lambda row : (row['height']*weights['height'] + 
                                             row['IQ']*weights['IQ'] + 
                                             row['income']*weights['income'])/3, 
                                             axis = 1)
```

Result:

|  | name | height | IQ | income | index |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Robert | 160 | 100 | 12 | 26.533333 |
| 1 | Sam | 170 | 140 | 7 | 34.366667 |
| 2 | Tom | 180 | 120 | 4 | 30.400000 |